# Passing pk in a get request function

Tags: django-rest-framework, python-requests

I am new to Django so I figure this question could be a bit stupid.I have an api endpoint that returns a list of Doctors(and their details) and another that returns one doctor(and his details)-this is the call am trying to make.I think the issue I am having is with how to ref the pk in the request url.
As it is, when I test on postman I get the error {
"errors": "JSONDecodeError('Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)',)",
"status": "error"
}
I am almost certain the issue is in api_services.py.I really hope someone can just point it out to me.

**views.py**

```
`class FinanceDoctorsView(GenericAPIView):
     authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication]
     permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

     @classmethod
     @encryption_check
     def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
     response = {}
     pk = kwargs.get("pk")
     try:
         result = {}
         auth = cc_authenticate()
         res = getDoctorInfo(auth["key"], pk)
         result = res
       
         return Response(result, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
            
     except Exception as e:
        error = getattr(e, "message", repr(e))
        result["errors"] = error
        result["status"] = "error"

     return Response(result, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)`
```

**api_services.py**

```
import requests

def getDoctorInfo(auth, params):

    print("getting doctorInfo from Callcenter")

    try:
 
        headers = {
                "Authorization": f'Token {auth}'
         }
        url = f'{CC_URL}/finance/doctor-info/<int:pk>'
        res = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
        print("returning doctorInfo response",  res.status_code)

        return res.json()

    except ConnectionError as err:
        print("connection exception occurred")
        print(err)

        return err
```

**urls.py**

```
path(
    "doctor-info/<int:pk>", views.FinanceDoctorsView.as_view(), name="doctor_info"
),
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in the api service file, you have made a typo

```
url = f'{CC_URL}/finance/doctor-info/<int:pk>'
```

Should had be

```
# as in the function you have defined params, 
# and I think it could have been renamed as pk

url = f'{CC_URL}/finance/doctor-info/{params}'
```

Comment: I am getting the same issue.I am starting to think that the issue is in the res = requests.get(url, headers=headers) .Maybe there is smt I need to pass in here as well